# Detect drops of water on a card and count the amount and its size OpenCV C++

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to get information such as the area occupied by water droplets on a water sensitive card, in which I must extract the area, the number of drops, and determine the largest drop as well as the smallest drop.

Example Image :

[image: Example image]

What I've done so far is the detection of the area that is wet, but I have difficulty detecting the drops and measuring their size and quantity.

Follow the code below,

If anyone can help, I appreciate it!

```
src = cv::imread("/Users/gustavovisentini/Documents/Developer/Desktop/OpenCV-Teste3.3.1/binary_image.png");

cout << "Loading Image...\n\n";
cvtColor( src, src_gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY );
blur( src_gray, src_gray, Size(3,3) );
Mat canny_output;
Canny( src_gray, canny_output, thresh, thresh*2 );

vector<vector<Point>> contours;
findContours( src_gray, contours, RETR_TREE, CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE );

vector<vector<Point> > contours_poly( contours.size() );
vector<Rect> boundRect( contours.size() );
vector<Point2f>centers( contours.size() );
vector<float>radius( contours.size() );

for( size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ )
{
    approxPolyDP( contours[i], contours_poly[i], 3, true );
    boundRect[i] = boundingRect( contours_poly[i] );
    minEnclosingCircle( contours_poly[i], centers[i], radius[i] );
}

Mat drawing = src.clone();

for( size_t i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++ )
{
    Scalar color = Scalar( rng.uniform(0, 256), rng.uniform(0,256), rng.uniform(0,256) );
    drawContours( drawing, contours_poly, (int)i, color );
    rectangle( drawing, boundRect[i].tl(), boundRect[i].br(), color, 2 );
    circle( drawing, centers[i], (int)radius[i], color, 2 );

}
stringstream temp;
temp << "Total: " << contours.size() << " - " << thresh << " - " << contours[1][1];
cv::putText(drawing, temp.str(), cv::Point(10,40), FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 0.7, CV_RGB(255, 0, 0));

imshow( "Contours", drawing );
```

Comment: Unless we can reproduce the problem we probably can't help here. These sorts of coding issues usually require a lot of set-up and time to understand the exact issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach using thresholding + contour filtering. Using this screenshotted input image:

[image]

We first convert the image to grayscale then Otsu's threshold to get a binary image

[image]

Next we find contours on the binary image, iterate through each contour, and filter using contour area. To determine the total area of the water droplets, we keep a `total_area` variable and sum the area of each contour. The number of droplets is the length of the number of contours on the mask. To determine the smallest or largest drop, we simply sort the contours based on ascending contour area. The first contour will be the smallest drop and the last contour will be that largest drop.

Here's the detected droplets, the number of drops, and the total area

[image]

```
Drops: 257
Total area: 31448.0
```

I implemented this approach in Python but you can easily convert it to C++

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load image, grayscale, Otsu's threshold
image = cv2.imread('1.png')
mask = np.zeros(image.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,0,255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Find contours and filter using contour area
cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]

total_area = 0
drops = len(cnts)
smallest = sorted(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)[0]
largest = sorted(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)[-1]
for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    total_area += area

# Draw largest and smallest drop onto a mask
cv2.drawContours(mask, [largest], -1, (255,255,255), -1)
cv2.drawContours(mask, [smallest], -1, (255,255,255), -1)

# Visualize result better
result = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask=thresh)
result[thresh==0] = (255,255,255)

print('Drops: {}'.format(drops))
print('Total area: {}'.format(total_area))
cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: I can't understand how this mask is generated in c ++ (mask = np.zeros(image.shape, dtype=np.uint8))

Comment: The idea is to create a blank black image that has the same size as the input image where every pixel is 0. In Python, images are represented using Numpy arrays but I'm not sure what the equivalent in C++ is

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help so far! Another problem I have is how to find water droplets that have no round shape. In this way I can classify what is gout and what was water drained by the card. Is it possible to know this format through **findContours**? Follows the image that has this different water droplet.

[image: Example image:]

Comment: Another detail to be found is the droplet size, since the card size is always 15cm x 7cm, can I use these measurements to determine the droplet size?